# I can't initialize the internal structure with local variables C#

Tags: c#, initialization, structure, local

I honestly tried googling the answer but couldn't.
Ok, i have a structure like this:

```
struct TestStruct 
        {   public int n;
            public struct _InnerStruct  {   public int m;   }   
            public  _InnerStruct InnerStruct;   
        }
```

And I can assign the value to some local variable in the **n field**:

```
static void  Main ()    
    {       
        int SomeLOCALvar = 1;
        TestStruct TEST_STRUCT = new TestStruct () { n = SomeLOCALvar };
    }
```

My problem is that I don't understand how to do exactly the same with the **m field**.
Why doesn't code like this compile:

```
TestStruct TEST_STRUCT = new TestStruct () { n = SomeLOCALvar, .InnerStruct.m = SomeLOCALvar };
```

What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the following should *work*:

```
TestStruct TEST_STRUCT = new TestStruct { n = SomeLOCALvar, InnerStruct = new _InnerStruct { m = SomeLOCALvar } };
```

However, frankly it would be a very bad idea to do that. Value types (structs) should almost always be immutable; a struct with public mutable fields like this is *incredibly* brittle, and it *will* cause confusion and broken code.

IMO, these should be `readonly struct`, with get-only properties, and constructors. For example:

```cs
readonly struct InnerStruct {
    public int M { get; }
    public InnerStruct(int m) => M = m;
}
readonly struct TestStruct 
{
    public int N { get; }
    public InnerStruct InnerStruct { get; }
    public TestStruct(int n, int m)
    {
        N = n;
        InnerStruct = new InnerStruct(m);           
    }
}
```

(they should also ideally both override `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString`, to prevent boxing)

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot.
Don't worry, I am writing the code for myself and no one will ever see it :).
I'm a beginner and self-taught, so the second example is more confusing for me so far than the first :) I hope this will soon become familiar to me too.

Comment: @ЛёхаМайтрейд fair enough, but it is an important concept. If value-type copy semantics aren't 100% clear to you: just use `class` - you'll make fewer mistakes. The mutable `struct` as shown in the question has a lot of scope for subtle errors.